# Bad Request (#400) Missing required parameters: id

Tags: php, yii2

**My Controller**:

```
public function actionCreate()

{
    $model = new SuratMasuk(['scenario' => 'create']);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
    {
        try
        {
           $picture = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFile');
           $model->imageFile = $_POST['SuratMasuk']['id_suratmasuk'].'.'.$picture->extension;

           if($model->save())
           {

               $picture->saveAs('uploads/' . $model->id_suratmasuk.'.'.$picture->extension);
               Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success','Data saved!');
               return $this->redirect(['view','id'=>$model->id_suratmasuk]);
           }
           else
           {
               Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error','Data not saved!');
               return $this->render('create', [
                     'model' => $model,
               ]);
           }
       }
       catch(Exception $e)
       {
          Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error',"{$e->getMessage()}");
      }
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

}
```

getting this error message when i try to save my post. and it just uploads the text not images. i've tried $model->save(false); but not working

i'm newbie on yii, i'll appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because you try to pass `id` here:

```
return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id_suratmasuk]);
```

and since `actionView` almost for sure requires `id` as parameter you get this error because `$model->id_suratmasuk` is empty.

- You need to set proper `rules()` in `SuratMasuk` model.
- Do not use `POST` variables directly, this is asking for being hacked.
- Do not use `save(false)` if you need to save anything that comes from user (validation is a must!).
- Add `rules()` for all attributes so there will be no surprises like with this `id_suratmasuk` being empty.
- Check result of `saveAs()` on `UploadedFile` instance - this can go `false` as well.

Comment: I never worked with Yii but is it wrong that he is pulling his `$model->imageFile` from `$_POST` array and not from `$_FILES` array?

Comment: It's pulled from `FILES` (through `UploadedFile::getInstance`) and then immediately overwritten using `POST` which is of course double bad.